# Convert into 1D list from multidimensional and multi type array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, nlp

I am doing my first project in NLP and and have encoded features of audio files (400 in length) using `towhee`. In the output, each row is encoding of each audio file. The output is as shown below:

```
0      [([[[-0.5464456  -0.27430105 -0.7668772  ...  ...
1      [([[[ 2.4055429   1.6134734   0.87733674 ...  ...
2      [([[[-1.36764    -1.158407   -2.8810601  ... -...
3      [([[[ 1.6112621   2.7935793   0.20885658 ... -...
4      [([[[-0.18209544  1.1110162  -0.61837935 ...  ...
Name: embeddings, Length: 400, dtype: object
```

The dimension of each row is: `(1, 1, 1, 99, 1024)`. The type of each item is:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.float32'>
```

I need help in flattening these into one list. My intermediate goal is to make and X,Y table and use it in SVM (Support Vector Machine) for supervised classification task. Intended output would look like this:

```
embeddings                  output
[0.55, 0.31, 0.12, ...]     Sad
[0.17, 0.65, 0.23, ...]     Happy
[0.82, 0.76, 0.19, ...]     Angry
[0.52, 0.71, 0.25, ...]     Neutral
```

Any help or even suggestion for different approach to achieve this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this was a simple problem to solve using numpy library. I had to convert all using `numpy.array()` funtion. Numpy takes care of all the different types and converts them into numpy array.

```
m = numpy.array(row[3])
```